# Change display of product price on product show page only

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change the way prices are displayed on the product show page for all product that match the criteria. I have the following code:

```
function sv_change_product_price_display() {
    global $product;

//  $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        if( has_term( 'joint', 'product_tag', $post->ID) ){
            return $price;
        }
        if( has_term( 'Flowers', 'product_cat', $post->ID) ) {
            $cost = $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true );
            $cost = round($cost / 28, 2);
            $cost = '<div class="amount"><b>Starting at $'.$cost.' per gram</b></div>';
            $price = $cost;
            return $price;  
        }       
    }
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_price_display' );
```

This works on the show page but it also changes the prices on the single product page as well which is not what I want happening. I have tried different hooks to no avail either.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try with below condition for **shop page** only.

```
if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && is_shop()) {
```